# Remove empty space and dot's in numbers using Javascript inside iMacros macro

Tags: javascript, imacros

From http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.javascript/beginner-how-to-remove-dot-s-and-empty-s/181476 I found what I was looking for but cant get the results I 'should'

There were also many other code snips tried.  :(

Looking to modify IP octals by removing spaces & dot's 
example  >> " 12.34. 56 789" modify into: "123456789"

'Answer' offered on the thread was using regular expression:

```
  var strNumber = '12.34.56.789';
 strNumber = strNumber.replace(/[^\d]/, '');
```

or

```
strNumber = strNumber.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

isnt working within my code ( using http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=19759 as a 'template'). There are other examples on the forum but following those examples are not a solution. ANY code that would work would be welcome. I know there are some good iMacros coders here  ... in hopes they have a suggestion

iMacros VERSION = 10.02.2823  Windows 7 x64

```
URL GOTO=geoip.hidemyass.com
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET ip {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
SET !VAR8 EVAL(" var strNumber='{{ip}}'; strNumber=strNumber.replace(/\D/g, ''); ")

SET !VAR8 EVAL(" var strNumber='{{ip}}'; strNumber=strNumber.replace(/\D/g, ''); ")

SET !VAR8 EVAL ("strNumber=\'{{ip}}\'; var strNumber = strNumber.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); ")

PROMPT {{!VAR8}}
```

The checking PROMPT is always returning the whole line of code starting at EVAL (" ... ") for any and all variations

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is not optimal, but if you don't find anything else that works, it could be helpful:

```
while (strNumber.indexOf(" ")>-1){ strNumber=strNumber.replace(" ", ""); }
while (strNumber.indexOf(".")>-1){ strNumber=strNumber.replace(".", ""); }
```

Comment: Try this: `SET !VAR8 EVAL("'{{ip}}'.replace(/\\s/g, '').replace(/\\./g, '');")`

Comment: @Shugar   Oh wow ... works like a charm ... and in my eyes very elegant .. now how do I give credit to you for best solution ??

Comment: If you wish so, upvote my comment or any of my answers on ‘stackoverflow’ ;)